# How to hide URL Path in PHP Print Out

Tags: google-chrome, printing, php

I'm printing a page of my PHP application with the ( ctrl + P ), at the base of the printout, the url path is shown..i.e 
http://
localhost:8080/student/result.php how can i hide this or customize it.
Thanks

Comment: What browser are you printing from? Printing, and the associated headers and footnotes are a browser feature.

Comment: I'm printing from Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Chrome, uncheck "Headers and Footers" in the bottom left corner of the printing preferences that come up.

[[image: Screenshot of Chrome printing preferences]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USESa.png)

---

Other browsers have a similar option. In fact, both Firefox and Internet Explorer seem to allow finer control of the position and content of headers and footers, rather than just a show/hide (which, according to forums, was only introduced to Chrome recently).